# Problema con Caracteres especiales al generar un xml con php

Tags: php, xml

Estoy generando un xml con codificacion iso8859-1 con php

```
$anim="ñandu";
$xml->startElement("animal");
    $xml->text($anim);
$xml->endElement(); // cierro animal
```

de esa manera el tag queda de la siguiente manera

```
<animal>&amp;andu</animal>
```

Existe alguna forma de que la ñ quedara en formato html, por ejemplo :

```
   <animal>&#241;andu</animal>
```

Comment: La ñ está quedando escapada HTML. Lo que buscas es que quede codificada Unicode...

Comment: ¿De dónde vienes los datos y qué usas para obtenerlos? Por ejemplo, si usas [la clase `DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php), me parece que está tiene métodos para especificar la codificación de los datos.